# A Banach space of (Hamel) dimension $\kappa$ exists if and only if $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, axiom-of-choice

A Banach space of (Hamel) dimension $\kappa$ exists if and only if $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$.

How will we prove the converse implication. One sided implication for Hilbert Space is proved in question: [Can you equip every vector space with a Hilbert space structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100950/168520)

If we don't assume Axiom of Choice, and we have a Banach space with (Hamel Basis B existence given). Will it be true $B^\Bbb N$ equinumerous with $B$?

Note: $B^\Bbb N$ is not empty as $B$ is specified.

Comment: As noted in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100952/151552, this is Lemma 2 in the paper "Badly incomplete normed linear spaces" by A.H. Kruse.

Comment: In case you do not have access to Kruse's article from Springer website, it is useful to know that older issues of [Mathematische Zeitschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematische_Zeitschrift) are freely available from GDZ: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?IDDOC=8487

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not true.

If $D$ is a Dedekind finite set with a Dedekind finite power set, then $\ell_1(D)$ is a Banach space which has a Hamel basis which is also a Schauder basis, and every linear operator from $\ell_1(D)$ to a normed space is continuous.

But if $D$ is Dedekind finite, then $|D|^{\aleph_0}>|D|$. So it suffices to assume that an infinite Dedekind finite set like that exists. Which is of course consistent with the failure of choice.

See also:

> Brunner, Norbert "**Garnir's dream spaces with Hamel bases.**"
>   *Arch. Math. Logik Grundlag.* **26** (1987), no. 3-4, 123–126.

Comment: Why Hamel Basis will be Schauder Basis. Schauder Basis are always countable while normed linear space has uncountable Hamel Basis. I think you want to say Hamel Basis has cardinality same as D

Comment: And I might be rude in asking questions and questions only. But If I assume axiom of countable choice atleast. What will be your conclsion.

Comment: (1) If you just assume a normed space, then it is perfectly possible to find one with a countable dimension. (2) Read the paper by Brunner. (3) If we assume countable choice, I don't know what happens, I imagine it might still be consistent that a counterexample holds, but it is probably going to be much more difficult to come by.

Comment: But proof given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340333/168520 I don't see were we using CC

Comment: Not every normed space is a Banach space. I never claimed that there is a Banach space of countable dimension.

Comment: Is it not true: 'No infinite-dimensional normed linear space with a countable Hamel basis can be complete'

Comment: Yes, it is true. How does that contradict what I said? Is every normed space complete?

Comment: in your answer you said: ℓ1(D) is a Banach space which has a Hamel basis which is also a Schauder basis,

Comment: And I said to that, read the paper.