# Can any uncountable dimensional real vector space be made into a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

On any real vector space $V$ of uncountable dimension , can we always define a norm such that endowed with that norm , $V$ becomes a complete normed linear space ? ( I know it can be done if $V$ is finite dimensional but what if $V$ is infinite dimensional ? The only thing I know is that any infinite dimensional Banach space must be of uncountable dimension  )

Comment: Why are the questions posed in title and body different?

Comment: Yes. No.        ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @To all : I think things are ok now

Comment: Hint: Two vector spaces of equal dimension are isomorphic as vector spaces (over a given field).

Comment: @SaunDev I took the liberty of changing the title into a somewhat more concise question (for the sake of readability). Oh yeah, forgot uncountable.

Comment: @k.stm : But uncountable dimensional is necessary otherwise the answer would be trivially no

Comment: @hardmath : Ok , so you are telling me to look , for each uncountable cardinal , to a real vector space which is complete ? Or something else ?

Comment: @SaunDev:  Yes, at least if I understood the question.  I did have some doubt whether you start with a *topological vector space* of uncountable dimension and expect to realize it by a complete norm (or even metric), which is clearly untenable.  But if you only have to preserve the dimension of $V$ as a vector space, then that's the approach I'd take.

Comment: @hardmath : Well I just need to preserve the dimension and algebraic properties , I am assuming no topological properties of the space beforehand . So what is(are) the familiar space(s) you are talking about ? Nothing really comes to mind :(

Comment: No, if the Hamel dimension is $\aleph_\omega$, then it is not a Banach space.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340939/a-banach-space-of-hamel-dimension-kappa-exists-if-and-only-if-kappa-ale)

Comment: Apparently, with the axiom of choice, a necessary and sufficient condition for a Banach space of infinite (algebraic) dimension $\kappa$ to exist is that $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$. If there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set, however, that condition is no longer necessary.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ok , so there is some very involved set theoretic concepts related too , I see ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a set theory expert, but I'd argue as follows:

Begin with your favorite Banach space $B$, forget its metric, and consider only its vector space structure. As a vector space, $B$ possesses a Hamel base $(e_\iota)_{\iota\in I}$ of a certain cardinality $|I|$.

Now if the dimension of your vector space $V$ equals $|I|$ you can copy the Banach space structure of $B$ over to $V$.

Comment: Yes , yes that is true , then the question reduces to " Does for every uncountable cardinal $\alpha$ , there exists a Banach space of dimension (Hamel basis dimension) $\alpha$ " ?